# Print CSS Hide the body and show a div inside the body

Tags: html, css

I found too much content on how to hide specific parts using css.

I do not want to hide multiple divs:

```
#flash,#menu,#anuncios { display:none; }
```

but I need to hide the whole body and just show a div inside the body.

I tried to set the body as:

```
body {
    display:none;
}

.print {
    display:block!important;
}
```

But everything is hidden.

How to hide all the content of the site with just one command? And show a div inside the site

Comment: You don't need to hide the body.

Comment: how do I hide all content without hiding the body? As I said before... I do not want to hide several elements. #flash,#menu,#anuncios { display:none; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the *all/universal* (`*`) and `:not` selectors:

```css
body *:not(#flash):not(#menu):not(#anuncios) {display: none}
```

```html
<div>Not here...</div>
<div id="flash">Hello</div>
<div id="menu">World</div>
<div id="anuncios">!</div>
<div>Also missing...</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. I tested on an html page and it worked. but I'm using the vue and when I tested it in vue it did not work. The vue has some peculiarity in relation to css. I'll research to try to find out. Not all content is hidden by using: not

Comment: @RenatoSouzadeOliveira Good to know, make sure that all the unhidden content is inside elements of your choice otherwise it stays visible, if done pure CSS way.

Answer (score 0):

I've done that in a website - wrap all the content you want to hide in some tag (mine is called `.main-content`, and add the following styles and elements:

```
<style>
    #print-message {
        display: none;
        direction: ltr;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 2rem 0;
    }
    @media print {
        .main-content {
            display: none;
        }
        #print-message {
            display: block;
        }
    }
</style>
```

This is the div that would show when the user tries to print things:

```
<div id="print-message">
    Printing Unavailable.
</div>
```